# Raphaël.js - swapping characters in text (animation)

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am having fun with `Raphaël.js` library.

Lets say we have text:

```
paper.text(10,10, "James");
```

On event `click` I want activate animation which swaps characters in this text.
So, for example:  "James" to "sameJ".

I want to see that animation how the letters are being changed.

Could you help me with this?

Any tips, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/sVB8C/13/embedded/result/

and have fun!!!

There is nothing related to RaphaelJS in particular, there is only a couple of javascript functions, the real problem its coming when you decide to add some line break to your text

**HTML**

```
<div id="holder" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -150px; margin-left: -200px; "></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var paper = Raphael("holder", 700, 300);

    var messageText = "Why don't try yourself before asking your question?";
    messageText = Swap(messageText);
    var msg = paper.text(0, 20, messageText).attr({ "text-anchor": "start", "font-size": 21, "font-family": "Courier New" });

    function Swap(text) {
      return text.split('').reverse().join('');
    }

    var array = messageText.split("");
    var loopTimer;
    msg[0].textContent = '';
    function Looper() {
      if (array.length > 0) {
        msg[0].textContent += array.shift();
      } else {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        return false;
      }
      loopTimer = setTimeout('Looper()', 70);
    };
    Looper();

    setTimeout(function () {
      messageText = Swap(messageText);
      array = messageText.split("");
      msg[0].textContent = '';
      Looper();
    }, 100 * messageText.length);
```